# WebDriverManager The import io.github cannot be resolved

Tags: maven, selenium, webdriver-manager

I added the below WebDriverManager maven dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In my java class I am unable to import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager; automatically. If manually write the import, I get error at io.github which says: The import io.github cannot be resolved.

What is the issue here? I tried clean, restart and different versions of webdrivermanager in pom.xml.

[image]

Comment: Remove `<scope>test</scope>` and it will work

Comment: That worked, Thanks. But how is that the issue? I would like to know what difference does it make with scope and without scope.

Comment: I will write the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The dependency you used is reduced to `<scope>test</scope>` but what that actually means?
It indicates that the dependency is NOT required for the compilation but only for execution.

It appears during the runtime and test but not during compilation.

The default scope is `compile`. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of the project.

EDIT:

`<scope>test</scope>` makes the dependency available for execution but not for compilation. What does it mean?

It means that the classpath is available for `src/test` folder in your project.

Default scope makes classpath available for `src/main` AND `src/test`. So if you make any classes manage WebDriver and you put them under source folder, you should use a scope which allows the dependency to be available at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In the scope replace with compile instead of test, it will import.*

Answer (score 0):

You also can not specify the scope, it will work too :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Windows 10
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers - 2020-12

Java JDK 15.0.2

Maven 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

The following pom.xml file is not working for me. I tried many versions for webdrivermanager but the line "import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;" always gives error.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebCrawling</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebCrawling</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>20</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```